# string can't be used to index type '{ firstName: { inputWarning: string; inputRegex: RegExp; };

Tags: reactjs, regex, typescript

```
 const checkRegexSignUp = {
    firstName: { inputWarning: "only letters", inputRegex: /^[a-z ,.'-]+$/i },
    lastName: { inputWarning: "only letters", inputRegex: /^[a-z ,.'-]+$/i },
  }
  const change = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { value, name } = e.target;
    RegExp(checkRegexSignUp[name].inputRegex).test(value)
      ? e.target.setCustomValidity("")
      : e.target.setCustomValidity(checkRegexSignUp[name].inputWarning);
    setFormSignUp({ ...formSignUp, [name]: value });
  };
```

I am getting an incomprehensible error

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ firstName: { inputWarning: string; inputRegex: RegExp; }; lastName: { inputWarning: string; inputRegex: RegExp; }; }'.

[image]

what is the problem ? How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider defining an explicit interface for `checkRegexSignUp`

```
interface RegexSignup {
  [key: string]: { inputWarning: string, inputRegex: RegExp }
}

const checkRegexSignUp: RegexSignup = {
  firstName: { inputWarning: "only letters", inputRegex: /^[a-z ,.'-]+$/i },
  lastName: { inputWarning: "only letters", inputRegex: /^[a-z ,.'-]+$/i },
}
```